# How to extend creditmemo save action in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.3, plugin, creditmemo, preference

I need to extend creditmemo save action:

- Update post data **before action method call**
- Update database **after creditmemo save**.

Which method is better **Plugin** or **preference** and if Plugin then how can I update post object?

Comment: Check my updated answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try with Plugin. The code below will work:

*etc/adminhtml/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="add_data_custom"
                type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\CreditmemoAddData"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

In your Plugin:

```
public function beforeSave(
     \Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoRepositoryInterface $subject,
     \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoInterface $entity
)
{
  //Your code here
}

public function afterSave(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoRepositoryInterface $subject,
    $result
) {

    //Your code here

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Did you try to clear Magento Cache and try again. It will work in case: saving Creditmemo. I'm using Magento 2.13 version.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will work. I checked and tested.

Comment: Ok let me try it again

Comment: Yes It's Working Thanx @KhoaTruongDinh

Comment: how can i get order is from it